# WPF Process.Start(url) how to know current URL or when window is closed

Tags: c#, wpf, url, browser, process

I have a WPF application that redirects to a payment system and then starts pooling a database to see if the transaction reference was posted back via a different channel.

I had a chat with one of my programmer friends and he said that there was no need for pooling and I could have simply tracked Url to which payment system redirects after successful payment and react accordingly.

Code to open window and redirect agent to payments system is as follows:

```
var process = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(url));
```

**Is there a way to get the Url of the Browser Window?**

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend to use a web browser control inside your application. There are very good ones and a built-in version (called [`WebBrowser`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser(v=vs.110).aspx)). `Process.Start` is a problem since you never know which browser (and version) is loaded. You have support a lot of different ways to get the URL.

The benefit of using a web browser control in your application is that you have absolute control of the web browser, you can handle events like loading of pages, which enables you to perform checks on the URL. I use this myself to do OAuth authentication on a client and get the token back from the URL and parse the token out of it.

Comment: An even better and faster one would be CefSharp. But the problem is that if used with WPF, it's slow, there's a workaround for that. But works great for WinForms.

Comment: Indeed, that is one of the alternatives with a much better browser than the built-in web browser.